# How to fix “#DIV/0!” error from Excel import?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that works properly in Excel. However, when I import it to Google Sheets it gives me the `#DIV/)!` error. I am at a loss for how to fix this.

I am trying to rank the items based on the number in column `P`. I would like for the highest number in column `P` to be ranked 1, then 2, 3, etc. If two numbers in column `P` are the same I would like for them to both be ranked the same. However, I don't want the formula to then skip the next number in the ranking order. Also, I am not sure if it matters, but column `P` displays a number but is technically filled with a formula to obtain that number. Example:

Points column is populated using the following formula:

```
=SUM(H2,J2,L2,N2,O2)
```

```
Points   Rank
5        3
3        4
8        1
3        4
6        2
2        5
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT((P2 < P$2:P$36)/COUNTIF(P$2:P$36,P$2:P$36))+1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you could try to use `=IFERROR(...` to set the value to NA or 0 if you receive an error.

Answer (score 2):

Add the opposite of the numerator to the denominator to ensure you never receive #DIV/0!.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((P2 < P$2:P$36)/(COUNTIF(P$2:P$36,P$2:P$36)+(P2 >= P$2:P$36)))+1
```

When (P2 < P$2:P$36) is false, the numerator will be zero so it doesn't matter what the denominator is as long as it isn't zero.